# saving data to mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am self learning nodeJS, Now I tried to insert data in MongoDB and this my goal

insert values in here and once submit button is clicked, should save the data successfully to mongodb and this should return a successful message.

[image]

But this is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
```

Here are the code snippets

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const address = process.argv[2];
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const app = express();

//INSERT TO MONGO DB
//connect to mongo db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/weathertest2');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


//create weather schema
const WeatherSchema = new Schema({
    location:{
        type: String
    },
    temperature:{
        type: String
    },
    observationTime:{
        type: String
    }

});

const Weather = mongoose.model('weather', WeatherSchema);

// post request
app.post('/new', function(req, res){
    new Weather({
        location    : req.body.location,
        temperature: req.body.temperature,
        observationTime   : req.body.observationTime                
    }).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.send('Successfully inserted!');
    });
});
 

// listen for request
app.listen(process.env.port || 9000, function(){
    console.log('now listening for  testing request');
});
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `body-parser` middleware alongside with express:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```js
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

/* 
* Parses the text as URL encoded data (which is how browsers tend to send
* form data from regular forms set to POST) and
* exposes the resulting object (containing the keys and values) on req.body
*/

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This way the data from the form should be included in the request `body` (`req.body.location`)

Comment: Glad I could help @rickyProgrammer !

Comment: i wanna ask, how can i return the input value in the temperature for example?

Comment: Please create another question for this ! Thanks !

Comment: in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008661/retrieve-data-from-mongodb-and-display-in-browser-using-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the body of the request is undefined. This might be because express isn't parsing the request body correctly. The solution is probably to use a body parser.

```
npm install --save body-parser
```

Then import body-parser into your file:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Then place this line before the "/new" handler:

```
app.use(bodyParser)
```